# QNetworkAccessManager, reset TCP connection

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking, tcp

I am writing a program in Qt to make HTTP request to an embedded device and using the QNetworkAccessManager to do this and it's working well except for the following case.

The embedded device only accepts 1 TCP connections. If the connection is dropped (cable pulled) while the TCP connection is active, the device gets into a hung state. It doesn't know the connection has dropped and can't accept anymore.

Is there a way to manually reset the QNetworkAccessManager so I can force a new connection on every request and close the connection gracefully when the request has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the reply, check if the `QNetworkRequest::HttpPipeliningWasUsedAttribute` attribute is set. If it is, then this is your problem: you must modify your request to force a false value on the `QNetworkRequest::HttpPipeliningAllowedAttribute`. Without pipelining, each request is sent on a separate connection.

Note that `QNetworkAccessManager` can initiate multiple requests in parallel. You'll have to make sure that you only ever allow one request to be outstanding, and to only place one new request when the previous one is finished.

Comment: Pipelining is disabled by, default. Do you know if when pipelining is disabled, the TCP connection is closed when the request is complete?

Comment: A workaround I have found is to re-create the QNetworkAccessManager after every reply. However this seems to be a bit scrappy.